# Calculating track position for a music seek bar

Tags: java, math, midi

How do I calculate the music track position on a seek bar?

I have created a plain music player GUI as a demo for a midi audio player and I want to create a seek bar for it.  I've created everything for it but I have been struggling to calculate the x position of the seek position indicator.

**Played for 2 seconds (Dimensions: 640x480)(TrackPosX: 260/475 where 475 is seek bar endX)**
[image]

**Snippet of my render method**

```
int trackPosY = this.getHeight()/2+this.getHeight()/4+40; //Y coordinate of seek bar/seek indicator/end and begin points

//Draws seek bar with end points        
g.drawLine(this.getWidth()/4, trackPosY, this.getWidth()/2+this.getWidth()/4, trackPosY);  //Draws Seek bar
g.drawLine(this.getWidth()/4, trackPosY-10, this.getWidth()/4, trackPosY+10); //Draws Begin point
g.drawLine(this.getWidth()/2+this.getWidth()/4+1, trackPosY-10, this.getWidth()/2+this.getWidth()/4+1, trackPosY+10); //Draws End line (Not sure why I have to add 1 to the x but if I don't the seek bar breaches the width of the end line.)

if(midiPlayer != null && (midiPlayer.getState() == SimpleMidiPlayer.PLAY || midiPlayer.getState() == SimpleMidiPlayer.PAUSE)){
    int trackLineLength = (this.getWidth()/4+this.getWidth()/2 - this.getWidth()/4); //Length of the line, not sure if necessary
    int trackPosX = (int) ((midiPlayer.getTickPosition()/trackLineLength*midiPlayer.getTicksTotal()/trackLineLength) + (this.getWidth()/4)); //Attempt at finding X Coordinate
    g.fillOval( trackPosX-3, trackPosY-3, 6, 6); //Draws Seek position indicator
    debugTrackPos.setDebugText("TrackPosX: "+trackPosX+"/"+(this.getWidth()/4+this.getWidth()/2)+" Tick: "+midiPlayer.getTickPosition()+"/"+midiPlayer.getTicksTotal()); //Debugging purposes (top left of pic)
}
```

Comment: If you divide your code into single purpose methods, I am sure it would be easier for you to implement. The way your code is formed now, it is quite hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your close, the basics go something like this:

```
ratio = var/total;
position = (max-min)*ratio +min
```

Your variables are:

```
var = midiPlayer.getTickPosition()
total = midiPlayer.getTicksTotal()
ratio = midiPlayer.getTickPosition()/midiPlayer.getTicksTotal()

(you already have max-min defined as trackLineLength)
max = this.getWidth()/4+this.getWidth()/2 
min = this.getWidth()/4
```

So using these variables you would have this result:

```
int trackPosX = (int)( ((double)midiPlayer.getTickPosition())/midiPlayer.getTicksTotal()
                * trackLineLength + this.getWidth()/4)
```

Note I added a `(double)`cast to the division on `getTickPosition/getTicksTotal`. My guess is these are integer values being returned and that division would result in 0 every time unless you cast it to a double.